# Unable to login with domain users through xrdp in RHEL 9

Tags: redhat

I have setup Xrdp in RHEL workstation for remote login from windows machine through mstsc.
And I have joined the RHEL workstation to Active directory server.
I am to login to local users create in RHEL workstation machine.
But I am not able to login with domain users